# How to check if a twilio token is expired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

I have a nextjs project and I need to verify if a twilio token is expired or not.

I thought about using the library `jwt-decode` to decode the token and take the *exp* attribute from it, then compare it to the actual date. The problem is that the *exp* date seems to be broken because it is always in 1970.

For example I have just created this token:

```
{
  "jti": "SKbec4a565d0598f1e4130f65db51a8345-xxxxxxxxxx",
  "grants": {
    "identity": "618f7ef057c2923be10dfd1d",
    "chat": {
      "service_sid": "ISbffc1a6c2f8647ac8a6774xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  },
  "iat": 1649879042,
  "exp": 1649882642,
  "iss": "SKbec4a565d0598f1e4130f6xxxxxxxxxx",
  "sub": "AC1d09a2edee3f481fbd1dafxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

If I do `new Date(1649882642)` it comes out to be `1970-01-20T02:18:02.642Z`. Always.

Maybe should I specify the token expiration when I create it? I created it following the [official doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens). So what should I do in order to determinate if a token is valid or not?

Comment: get the (currentDateTime+expirationTime) and store it. Every-time a new request comes in, check if the newCurrentDate  <= than the above, if yes it's valid otherwise it's invalid. expirationTime is your's to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iat` and `exp` values in a Twilio JWT are the time in seconds since the epoch (1st January 1970).

However, [Dates in JavaScript are measured in milliseconds since the the epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters).

So, to adjust the time in seconds to the date in JavaScript you should multiply by 1,000 first.

```js
const exp = decodedToken.exp;
const expiryDate = new Date(exp * 1000);
```

In your example, that looks like:

```js
const exp = 1649882642;
const expiryDate = new Date(exp * 1000);
expiryDate.toISOString();
// => 2022-04-13T20:44:02.000Z
```